What is 'StaticGenerationSearchParamsBailoutProvider' in nextjs?
I'm getting constantly:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of StaticGenerationSearchParamsBailoutProvider.

in my next app also I'm using dynamic loading with SSR disabled. What is StaticGenerationSearchParamsBailoutProvider anyway?
